# Opencart facebook parse page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, opencart, metadata

I have problem with parse/display my shop into Facebook. 
When I paste url (like) http://exclusivum.isoft.biz.pl/zmishuvachi-grohe Facebook display random data.

I know that I have to add meta og:
My url http://exclusivum.isoft.biz.pl/zmishuvachi-grohe have meta og like

```
<meta property="og:description" content="test"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://exclusivum.isoft.biz.pl/image/cache/catalog/logo-no1- 300x300.png" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="300"/>
<meta property="og:image:height" content="300"/>        
<meta property="og:site_name" content="EXCLUSIVUM.COM"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
```

When I use https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/ I have response:

```
Inferred Property
The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Meta Tags In Body
Your page has meta tags in the body instead of the head. This may be because your HTML was malformed and they fell lower in the parse tree.
Please fix this in order for the tags to be usable.
Inferred Property
The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property
The 'og:title' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property
The 'og:description' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property
The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Share App ID Missing
The 'fb:app_id' property should be explicitly provided, Specify the app ID so that stories shared to Facebook will be properly attributed to the app. Alternatively, app_id can be set in url when open the share dialog.
```

It't look like FB does not see my tags.

Comment: one problem could be because you are loading a LOT of stuff before the og tags (js, css, fonts). you should not do that. you should also minify all code, and read about optimization in general. for example, concat scripts if you don´t use http/2. anyway, put the og tags up, before any js/css stuff.

Comment: I'm put og tags upper. After <title> but it's not change my problem.

Comment: another reason could be the wrong image size. you should use images as per facebook definition, not quadratic ones. 1200x630 is recommended according to the docs.